# jQuery Append Prepend to dynamically created li with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I have the following issue. I have this HTML

`<ul class="buildings-list">
    <li class="gchoice_20_0">
       <input name="input_20" type="radio" value="House" checked="checked" />
       <label for="choice_20_0" id="label_20_0">House</label>
    </li>
</ul>`

I want to prepend `<span class="house-icon"></span>` in this **li**. So this is js:

`jQuery('.buildings-list li label:contains("House")').parent().prepend('<span class="building-icon"></span>');`

But these **li**'s are generated dynamically via AJAX. How can I hook a listener to the latest fetched li's label, so that I can check if it contains "House", "Office" or anything else so that I can put the appropriate icon? Thanks

Comment: You can use variable instead of `House` use that to achieve required thing!

Answer (score 0):

For dinamic AJAX content, JQuery has specific methods, like `.live()` (wich is deprecated) and `.on()`

Check out the API documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/